# Ideas for solving a horrible 2nd order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have been trying to solve the following linear differential equation.
I would like to try to solve it as anallitically as possible.
Before I just try to approximate the nonlinear term and see how far it gets...

$-A u(x)-u''(x)-B \alpha ^2   \sinh ^2(\alpha  x) \text{csch}^2(2 \alpha  x) u(x)=0$

A , B and α are real constants

Or possibly linearize it... somehow.

Thanks for your help/suggestions/comments!

Comment: Looks linear to me. Is there a typo? Or do $A$, $B$, or $\alpha$ depend on $u$?

Comment: A , B and α are real constants. But the term $\sinh ^2(\alpha  x) \text{csch}^2(2 \alpha  x) u(x)$ is not linear

Comment: It is linear in $u(x)$, which is what is meant by linearity in a differential equation. Its coefficient $B\alpha^2\sinh^2(\alpha x)\text{csch}^2(2\alpha x)$ is nonlinear in $x$, but that does not matter when discussing the linearity of a differential equation. This differential equation is linear with variable coefficients.

Comment: I agree. I'm updating the tittle.

Comment: Note that $\sinh(x)\text{csch}(2x)=\frac{1}{2}\text{sech}(x)$

Comment: I suggest you try finding series solutions.